# How to instantiate a class multiple times based on a user input?

Tags: javascript, loops, class, instantiation

I'm trying to create a board game and would like to instantiate the class Human based on a number of times provided by the user. Obviously I'm trying to assign a different ID per object and the following loop doesn't work in order to instantiate the number of players:

```
var question = prompt('how many players');
var numOfPlayers = parseInt(question);

class Human {
  constructor (id) {
    this.id = id;
    this.health = 100;
    this.hammer = false
    this.knife = false;
    this.sword = false;
    this.baseballbat = false;
    this.damage = 0;
    this.location = {
      x: Math.floor(Math.random() * 8),
      y: Math.floor(Math.random() * 8)
    }
  }

  moveTo(x, y){
    this.location.x += x;
    this.location.y += y;
  }
}

var i;
for (i = 0; i < numOfPlayers; i++) {
    const player = new Human(id = i);
}
```

Comment: `new Human(i);`, no need to do `id = i`. Also, you may want to push the new instances into an array or something, because each iteration creates an instance that get destroyed immediately

Comment: The thing is you are successfully instantiating the number of players but the scope for the object is within the loop you cannot access it outside.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, I hope I have understood what you are trying to achieve here. The scope of the "const player" is limited within the loop. If you want to be able to access it outside the loop you need to declare a list/array likewise.

Code may go like this for the same:

```
var players = [];
for(let i = 0; i < numOfPlayers; i++) {
    players.push(new Human(i));
}
```

*Note: If you don't want to use variable 'i' outside the loop you can declare it inside 'for' using 'let' keyword as can be seen in the code above.*

Comment: seems I need to _let_ instead of _var_ here to keep the scope limited to for loop. In javascript _var_ has scope over entire function.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Human {
    constructor (id){
        this.id = id;
        this.health = 100;
        this.hammer = false
        this.knife = false;
        this.sword = false;
        this.baseballbat = false;
        this.damage = 0;
        this.location = {
            x:Math.floor(Math.random()*8),
            y:Math.floor(Math.random()*8)
        }

        console.log(`Human created with id of ${id}`); //Remove this just to show you that your class is being instantiated for each 'player'
    }

    moveTo(x,y){
        this.location.x += x;
        this.location.y += y;
    }
}

let numOfPlayers = prompt('How many players?');

const _init = () => {
    if(parseInt(numOfPlayers) > 0) {
        for (let i = 0; i < numOfPlayers; i++) {
            new Human(i)
        }
    }
}

_init();
```

Comment: How does this answer the question?